# Read lines of integers into an array in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I need to read integers seperated by line breaks into an array to be able to find maximum and minimum values. I'm using VB.Net 2010.

Comment: That's a nice homework :-) I think, you need a streamreader and a List(of Integer). What did you done so far?

Comment: I was trying to use streamreader but it was reading empty strings for some reason.

Comment: It works now: I tried it again and streamreader work fine, I have now idea what I was doing wrong the first time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functional approach with LINQ and C#7 ValueTuple feature (not so effective as `Array.ConvertAll`)

```
Dim summary =
    text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
         Select(AddressOf Integer.Parse).
         GroupBy(Function(value) 1).
         Select(Function(group) (Min:=group.Min(), Max:=group.Max())).
         DefaultIfEmpty((Min:=0, Max:=0)).
         First()

Dim minValue = summary.Min
Dim maxValue = summary.Max
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim lines = text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
Dim integers = Array.ConvertAll(lines, AddressOf Int32.Parse)
Dim min = integers.Min()
Dim max = integers.Max()
```

Comment: Because of `Array.ConvertAll` - usually people forget about this effective function.